# Update trigger that affects only modified columns

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, triggers, nested

I am trying to create a trigger that will only update columns if their value has been changed. From what I've read this could be done by comparing inserted and deleted tables. Below is how I'm trying to do the comparison.

Is there any other way? I think the `select` queries and the `if` statements can be nested in some ways, but I can't figure out how.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_Persoane_Update]
   ON [dbo].[Persoane]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @DFirstName varchar(30), 
            @IFirstName varchar(30), 
            @DLastName varchar(30),
            @ILastName varchar(30)

    SELECT  @DFirstName=D.FirstName, @DLastName=D.LastName
    FROM Deleted AS D
    SELECT  @IFirstName=I.FirstName, @ILastName=I.LastName
    FROM Inserted AS I

    IF @DFirstName <> @IFirstName
        BEGIN
            UPDATE FirstName
            SET  FirstName = @IFirstName
            WHERE FirstName = @DFirstName
        END
    IF @DLastName <> @ILastName 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE LastName
            SET  LastName = @ILastName
            WHERE LastName = @DLastName
        END 

END
```

I also tried this approach, but I fail to use CASE statement properly.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_Persons_Update]
   ON [dbo].[Persons]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT  D.FirstName, D.LastName, D.ID_Title, I.FirstName, I.LastName, I.ID_Title,
            CASE WHEN D.FirstName <> I.FirstName
                    THEN
                        BEGIN
                            UPDATE Persons
                            SET  FirstName = I.FirstName
                            WHERE FirstName = D.FirstName
                            PRINT 'FirstName modified'
                        END
            /*END                       
            CASE*/ WHEN D.LastName <> I.LastName
                    THEN
                        BEGIN
                            UPDATE Persons
                            SET  LastName = I.LastName
                            WHERE LastName = D.LastName
                            PRINT 'LastName modified'
                        END 
            /*END                       
            CASE*/ WHEN D.ID_Title <>   I.ID_Title
                    THEN
                        BEGIN
                            UPDATE Persons
                            SET ID_Title=I.ID_Title
                            WHERE ID_Title=D.ID_Title
                        END
            END
    FROM DELETED AS D
        INNER JOIN INSERTED AS I ON D.ID_Person=I.ID_Person
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for the first name:

```
update fn
    set firstname = id.newfname
    from firstname fn join
         (select i.firstname as newfname, d.firstname as oldfname
          from inserted i join
               deleted d
               on i.personid = d.personid
          where i.firstname <> d.firstname
         ) id
         on fn.firstname = id.oldname;
```

You shouldn't assume that `inserted` and `deleted` contain only one value.  This requires an `id` that matches the two view (`inserted` and `deleted` are actually views and not tables).

Comment: Is it possible to do both FirstName and LastName in the same update statement?

Comment: Where could I place a PRINT statement in order to observe which one of the columns was updated?

Comment: In an application, if multiple updates are attempted by different users, the id is required to match the two views or each update has its own inserted and deleted 'tables'? (one attempt/user).

Comment: @TanatosDaniel . . . The `inserted` and `deleted` tables are going to be specific to one invocation of `update`.  Hence, data will not be mixed from different users.

Comment: Ok. Could you please help me with my other two questions?